# A good Linux alternative to Ubuntu for a working environment

Tags: linux, laptop, linux-distributions

Im running a decent laptop with 3GB ram and 2GHz Core Duo. I use it mainly for working which requires several SSH and SFTP connections to servers and running a VM most of the time. Nothing much more intensive than that.

I like using Ubuntu 9.10 however I have the issue of Nautilus and the top/bottom menus freezing up on me constantly - dare I say it, alot more problems than when I was using Windows Vista.

Im just looking for recommendations of other operating systems which would be suitable for the task.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the GUI is the only problem, but you like the system itself, then install [Kubuntu](http://www.kubuntu.org/). It's basically Ubuntu with a different user interface, including [Dolphin](http://dolphin.kde.org/) instead of Nautilus.

Comment: Actually there's no need to make a totally new install just to switch to KDE. Just install (as root) the `kubuntu-desktop` package via e.g. `synaptics` (or with `aptitude` on the command line: `aptitude install kubuntu-desktop`). Then select KDE as session when logging in. And of course, this can be uninstalled easily, too.

Comment: Bear in mind when doing this that you will still have all your gnome utilities installed, and many of these will have kde duplicates.

Comment: Thank you, I shall try the quicker way honk mentioned first then a clean install of Kubuntu if needed. Hopefully Dolphin wont have the same problems.

Comment: Just thinking though, if I was going by a fresh install, would it be better to install Kubuntu 9.04 (not 9.10) for reasons Cry Havok mentioned?

Comment: @Roozak: You can uninstall gnome if you want. I think it is in `gnome-desktop-environment`, but am not sure.

Comment: See http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/purekde and http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/purexfce .

Comment: @Yktula: if one would need this I would file a bug in launchpad: the packages listed there should in principle all be pulled in/removed as dependencies of the `*-desktop` virtual packages.

Btw, nice Ubuntu-forum style hint, `sudo bli bla` without any explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would go with [Fedora](http://fedoraproject.org/) or [RedHat](http://www.redhat.com/) instead of Ubuntu.

They're all free. If you try one and don't like it, switch to another.

I'm very big Apple user though, TextMate sunk it's hooks in deep.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 9.10 has a large number of problems compared to 9.04 - take a look at the Ubuntu forums and lists.  If you're happy with Ubuntu you may benefit from using 9.04 instead (assuming you've already applied all available updates) until 10.4 is released (which should happen in about a month).

I've been running 10.04 since Alpha 3 on my netbook and it's been just fine, no lockups or other problems.  I'd be very confident that 10.04 will be much more reliable than 9.10.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. A colleague actually mentioned similar to what you said.  I shall resort to 9.04 if KDE gives me problems.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenSUSE](http://www.opensuse.org/) is awesome, stable, and has a great KDE integration. I will never go back to Ubuntu after trying OpenSUSE, now running on all of my computers (including at work), and my girlfriend's.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to try Mandriva or maybe Linux Mint (derivated from ubuntu).
Mandriva has an excellent hardware recognition. 
Mint has also a great graphics!